# Deleting records from Apache Hudi Table which is part of Glue Tables created using AWS Glue Job and Kinesis

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-dynamodb, aws-glue, apache-hudi

[image: Setup overview]

I currently have a DynamoDB stream configured which is inputing streams into Kinesis Data streams whenever insertion/updation happens and subsequently I have Glue tables which is taking input from above kinesis stream and then displaying the structural schema and also a Glue script is helping me create a Hudi Table which can be accessed using Athena. I'm currently able to monitor streaming data and able to see insertions/updations (simulating from boto3 using pycharm in my local machine) in my Athena table. Can we perform deletions aswell using the same Glue Job?

My Glue Script helping me create Glue Table (Hudi Table) looks as below -

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame, Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import * 
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, to_timestamp, monotonically_increasing_id, to_date, when
import datetime
from awsglue import DynamicFrame

import boto3

## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME", "database_name", "kinesis_table_name", "starting_position_of_kinesis_iterator", "hudi_table_name", "window_size", "s3_path_hudi", "s3_path_spark" ])

spark = SparkSession.builder.config('spark.serializer','org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer').config('spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet','false').getOrCreate()
                    
sc = spark.sparkContext
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

database_name = args["database_name"]
kinesis_table_name = args["kinesis_table_name"]
hudi_table_name = args["hudi_table_name"]
s3_path_hudi = args["s3_path_hudi"]
s3_path_spark = args["s3_path_spark"]

commonConfig = {'hoodie.datasource.write.hive_style_partitioning' : 'true','className' : 'org.apache.hudi', 'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.use_jdbc':'false', 'hoodie.datasource.write.precombine.field': 'id', 'hoodie.datasource.write.recordkey.field': 'id', 'hoodie.table.name': hudi_table_name, 'hoodie.consistency.check.enabled': 'true', 'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.database': database_name, 'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.table': hudi_table_name, 'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.enable': 'true', 'path': s3_path_hudi}

partitionDataConfig = { 'hoodie.datasource.write.keygenerator.class' : 'org.apache.hudi.keygen.ComplexKeyGenerator', 'hoodie.datasource.write.partitionpath.field': "partitionkey, partitionkey2 ", 'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.partition_extractor_class': 'org.apache.hudi.hive.MultiPartKeysValueExtractor', 'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.partition_fields': "partitionkey, partitionkey2"}

incrementalConfig = {'hoodie.upsert.shuffle.parallelism': 68, 'hoodie.datasource.write.operation': 'upsert', 'hoodie.cleaner.policy': 'KEEP_LATEST_COMMITS', 'hoodie.cleaner.commits.retained': 2}

combinedConf = {**commonConfig, **partitionDataConfig, **incrementalConfig}

glue_temp_storage = s3_path_hudi

data_frame_DataSource0 = glueContext.create_data_frame.from_catalog(database = database_name, table_name = kinesis_table_name, transformation_ctx = "DataSource0", additional_options = {"startingPosition": "TRIM_HORIZON", "inferSchema": "true"})

def processBatch(data_frame, batchId):
    if (data_frame.count() > 0):

        DataSource0 = DynamicFrame.fromDF(data_frame, glueContext, "from_data_frame")
        
        your_map = [
            ('eventName', 'string', 'eventName', 'string'),
            ('userIdentity', 'string', 'userIdentity', 'string'),
            ('eventSource', 'string', 'eventSource', 'string'),
            ('tableName', 'string', 'tableName', 'string'),
            ('recordFormat', 'string', 'recordFormat', 'string'),
            ('eventID', 'string', 'eventID', 'string'),
            ('dynamodb.ApproximateCreationDateTime', 'long', 'ApproximateCreationDateTime', 'long'),
            ('dynamodb.SizeBytes', 'long', 'SizeBytes', 'long'),
            ('dynamodb.NewImage.id.S', 'string', 'id', 'string'),
            ('dynamodb.NewImage.custName.S', 'string', 'custName', 'string'),
            ('dynamodb.NewImage.email.S', 'string', 'email', 'string'),
            ('dynamodb.NewImage.registrationDate.S', 'string', 'registrationDate', 'string'),
            ('awsRegion', 'string', 'awsRegion', 'string')
        ]

        new_df = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = DataSource0, mappings=your_map, transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")
        abc = new_df.toDF()
        
        inputDf = abc.withColumn('update_ts_dms',to_timestamp(abc["registrationDate"])).withColumn('partitionkey',abc["id"].substr(-1,1)).withColumn('partitionkey2',abc["id"].substr(-2,1))
        
        

        # glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = DynamicFrame.fromDF(inputDf, glueContext, "inputDf"), connection_type = "marketplace.spark", connection_options = combinedConf)
        glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = DynamicFrame.fromDF(inputDf, glueContext, "inputDf"), connection_type = "custom.spark", connection_options = combinedConf)


glueContext.forEachBatch(frame = data_frame_DataSource0, batch_function = processBatch, options = {"windowSize": "10 seconds", "checkpointLocation":  s3_path_spark})


job.commit()
```

How do I implement deletion / script to reflect deletion changes in my dynamodb table in the same script? Is it even possible?

EDIT:

Added below lines to script. Resulting in deletion of all rows and empty table in Athena.

```
deleteDataConfig = {'hoodie.datasource.write.operation': 'delete'}


combinedConf = {**commonConfig, **partitionDataConfig, **incrementalConfig, **deleteDataConfig}
```

EDIT: Trying to add something like this in script after referring documentation of hudi

```
deleteConfig = {'hoodie.datasource.write.operation': 'delete', 'hoodie.delete.shuffle.parallelism': '1'}
```

Resulting in

```
23/01/18 13:35:06 ERROR ProcessLauncher: Error from Python:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/glue_job_script.py", line 79, in <module>
    glueContext.forEachBatch(frame = data_frame_DataSource0, batch_function = processBatch, options = {"windowSize": "10 seconds", "checkpointLocation":  s3_path_spark})
  File "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awsglue/context.py", line 678, in forEachBatch
    raise e
  File "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awsglue/context.py", line 668, in forEachBatch
    query.start().awaitTermination()
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/streaming.py", line 101, in awaitTermination
    return self._jsq.awaitTermination()
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1305, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 117, in deco
    raise converted from None
pyspark.sql.utils.StreamingQueryException: An exception was raised by the Python Proxy. Return Message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 2442, in _call_proxy
    return_value = getattr(self.pool[obj_id], method)(*params)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 196, in call
    raise e
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 193, in call
    self.func(DataFrame(jdf, self.sql_ctx), batch_id)
  File "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awsglue/context.py", line 653, in batch_function_with_persist
    batch_function(data_frame, batchId)
  File "/tmp/glue_job_script.py", line 76, in processBatch
    glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = DynamicFrame.fromDF(inputDf, glueContext, "inputDf"), connection_type = "custom.spark", connection_options = combinedConf)
  File "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awsglue/dynamicframe.py", line 644, in from_options
    format_options, transformation_ctx)
  File "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awsglue/context.py", line 334, in write_dynamic_frame_from_options
    format, format_options, transformation_ctx)
  File "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awsglue/context.py", line 357, in write_from_options
    return sink.write(frame_or_dfc)
  File "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awsglue/data_sink.py", line 39, in write
    return self.writeFrame(dynamic_frame_or_dfc, info)
  File "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awsglue/data_sink.py", line 32, in writeFrame
    return DynamicFrame(self._jsink.pyWriteDynamicFrame(dynamic_frame._jdf, callsite(), info), dynamic_frame.glue_ctx, dynamic_frame.name + "_errors")
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1305, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 111, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o318.pyWriteDynamicFrame.
: org.apache.hudi.exception.HoodieIOException: Deletes issued without any prior commits
    at org.apache.hudi.client.AbstractHoodieWriteClient.setWriteSchemaForDeletes(AbstractHoodieWriteClient.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hudi.client.SparkRDDWriteClient.getTableAndInitCtx(SparkRDDWriteClient.java:484)
    at org.apache.hudi.client.SparkRDDWriteClient.getTableAndInitCtx(SparkRDDWriteClient.java:448)
    at org.apache.hudi.client.SparkRDDWriteClient.delete(SparkRDDWriteClient.java:254)
    at org.apache.hudi.DataSourceUtils.doDeleteOperation(DataSourceUtils.java:229)
    at org.apache.hudi.HoodieSparkSqlWriter$.write(HoodieSparkSqlWriter.scala:194)
    at org.apache.hudi.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:164)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:220)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withTracker(SQLExecution.scala:232)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.executeQuery$1(SQLExecution.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withTracker(SQLExecution.scala:232)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:772)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:438)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:415)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:301)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.marketplace.connector.SparkCustomDataSink.writeDynamicFrame(CustomDataSink.scala:45)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.DataSink.pyWriteDynamicFrame(DataSink.scala:72)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Is this even the right way ? Kindly help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Was able to solve it by adding delete configs!

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Hudi can achieve deletes if the version is greater than 0.5.1

```
df.write.format("org.apache.hudi").
options(getQuickstartWriteConfigs).
option(OPERATION_OPT_KEY,"delete").
option(PRECOMBINE_FIELD_OPT_KEY, "ts").
option(RECORDKEY_FIELD_OPT_KEY, "uuid").
option(PARTITIONPATH_FIELD_OPT_KEY, "partitionpath").
option(TABLE_NAME, tableName).
mode(Append).
save(basePath);
```

[Reference](https://hudi.apache.org/blog/2020/01/15/delete-support-in-hudi/)
[Reference](https://hudi.apache.org/docs/writing_data/)